# DPDK send customized pkt but fail to receive

Tags: c, dpdk

I'm trying to send customized packages with dpdk, but i find that some package structure will make it fail to receive. For example, i define the package structure like this:

```
union my_pkt{
   struct hdr{
       uint32_t id;
       uint32_t name_len;
       uint64_t tsc;
       uint8_t name[100];
   }__attribute__((__packed__)) pkt_hdr;
   char buff[500];
};
```

My server running dpdk can only receive 1st batch of pkts, but the returned value of rte_eth_tx_burst() shows much more packages which have been sent.
However , if i modify the structure as below:

```
union my_pkt{
   struct hdr{
       uint32_t id;
       uint32_t name_len;
       uint32_t tsc[2];//modify this line
       uint8_t name[100];
   }__attribute__((__packed__)) pkt_hdr;
   char buff[500];
};
```

Sending and receiving both work correctly. The only difference between two structures is that the uint64_t timestamp were replace by an uint32_t array consisting of 2 items. I debug into the i40e driver code but can not understand where it goes wrong.

Can anybody help me? thanks!

Comment: Do you add an ethernet header you you just send the buffer as is?

Comment: I use rte_eth_promiscuous_enable() in code to enable all used port's promiscuous mode, and i used to do experiment on two server whose NICs linked directly and find that they can communicate correctly without ethernet header.

Comment: Well, that is the issue then, because depending on the Ethertype some frames might be dropped/consumed by the NIC. You can check the rte_eth_stats_get() to confirm if the packets were dropped by the NIC.

Comment: OK, i will try this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not clear from your description, you probably should add an Ethernet header at the beginning of you buffer, i.e.:

```
union my_pkt{
   struct hdr{
       struct ether_hdr; // Ethernet header
       uint32_t id;
       uint32_t name_len;
       uint64_t tsc;
       uint8_t name[100];
   }__attribute__((__packed__)) pkt_hdr;
   char buff[500];
};
```

And then fill it with destination/source MACs and type in your code.