# In what case would NIC report a rx_length_error?

Tags: nic, dpdk

I use dpdk to do packet-transmission experiment. However, the receiver application didn't receive any packets at all. The statistic data got from rte_eth_stats_get() showed that all ports reported many "rx_error". After debugging i found that all these errors are errors named "rx_length_error". A explanation from google says that a length error occurs if an incoming packet length field in MAC header doesn't match the packet length. However, as far as i know ,there is no length field in MAC header.

So my question is How does the NIC report this length error without a length field?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pointed in [your previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160477/dpdk-send-customized-pkt-but-fail-to-receive) that the Ethernet header need to be set properly, especially the Ethertype.

Some Ethertypes imply you have a fixed length frame, so 82599 recognize those frames and drop them if the expected length for the given Ethertype does not match your actual frame size.

Comment: I added the ether_hdr in packet as your suggestion in that question and it worked very well. Thanks for your help. But i am still confused about why does the packets transmit correctly in some case without an ether_hdr? For example , i just appended a simple character string into tx mbuf and the receiver could also receive all these strings without any rx-error.

Comment: @K.Xu because basically a random data is being inserted into the Ethertype field. So in some cases it works, in other cases it does not. It will also depend on the NIC, so on 82599 it drops some Ethertypes, while on another NIC it might drop some other... To save some CPU cycles, you can pre-populate the same Ethernet header over all your mbufs. But it is quite unsafe to insert a data instead of the Ethernet header.

Comment: Can this filter strategy be modified in dpdk driver code? Or it is just implemented by hardware in NIC?

Comment: @K.Xu not that I know

Comment: Thanks for your help!  :)